# Log4Net. How to disable internal debug

Tags: log4net, log4net-configuration

I got some test console application with log4net and AdoNetAppender.

When I launch application I have log4net debug info in console(log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] Could not open database connection)
I initialize AdoNetAppender ConnectionString via code.

When I set `<log4net debug="false">` it doesn't help.

I check `log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging;
             log4net.Util.LogLog.QuietMode;` properties after I read config file and configure log4net repository. They are both 'False'.

Why debug disabling doesn't work ?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you have it enabled with application settings in app.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="log4net.Internal.Debug" value="true"/>
</appSettings>
```

This seems to ovverride the setting on the `log4net` node.

Comment: No App.Config contains only configSections and connectionStrings blocks